How to write a If else condition in github action workflow yaml file?
Previously, I implemented a YAML workflow.it only works when both types of files are pushed simultaneously. If either a C or C++ file is pushed individually, the YAML workflow fails to execute. The code is given below ,
name: Clang Static Analysis

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development/*
      - test/*
      - feature/*
      
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run Clang Static Analysis
        run: clang --analyze src/*.c

      - name: Run Static Code Analysis (C++)
        run: clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp

So, clang static code analysis, should work through the workflow when I push either C or CPP or BOTH.
If I push both types of files , it works smoothly. If I push one type(eg, C) only, it would be failed.I have tried(pushed one type of file),got error like below
Run clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp
  clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/*.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


Your question, especially desired output is unclear. Can you clarify your desired output? what do you want to achieve ?

Hi @Hujaakbar,
I have updated my question as per your suggestion.

Is that your complete workflow? What's the exact error that you get? You're running it for all the C and C++ files. Should always work no matter if it's a .c or .cpp file.

Hi @Azeem,
This is created for simple test purpose. When I try to push one type(eg, C) of code, The error like below
Run clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp   clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp   shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0} clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/*.cpp' clang: error: no input files Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Hi @JasmiVInay, Why is that? Are you filtering files before running the analyzer? If there's no filtering and the complete repo is being checked out then the existing files should already be there and it shouldn't fail unless I'm missing something here.

Hi @Azeem,
I want this workflow to run either if any one of the language present. But here, if C file is present and CPP  is not present , it gets failed and vice versa. That was my question.

Do you currently have both .c and .cpp files in the src directory?

@Azeem,
yes, for some demo purpose

@JasmiVInay: Then, both clang and clang++ commands should work fine. However, the error "no such file or directory" means that those file(s) are missing somehow. You need to run ls -l *.{c,cpp} before running analyze steps. See if .c and .cpp files present or not. Add its output in your question as well.

GitHub Actions runner doesn't support else clause.
But you can achieve desired output using various hacks.
Based on your code, it seems that both clang and clang++ steps are trigged by the same set of conditions
 - name: Run Clang Static Analysis (C)
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.added, 'src/') || contains(github.event.head_commit.modified, 'src/') }}
    run: clang --analyze src/*.c

  - name: Run Static Code Analysis (C++)
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.added, 'src/') || contains(github.event.head_commit.modified, 'src/') }}
    run: clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp

If you want to run "Static Code Analysis (C++)" regardless of "Clang Static Analysis (C)" fails or not , you can use !cancelled() expression to achieve your desired output results.
!cancelled()

If you want to run a job or step regardless of previous step/job's success or failure, use :
if: ${{ !cancelled() }}

Your yaml file would look like this
 - name: Run Clang Static Analysis (C)
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.added, 'src/') || contains(github.event.head_commit.modified, 'src/') }}
    run: clang --analyze src/*.c

  - name: Run Static Code Analysis (C++)
    if: ${{ !cancelled() && (contains(github.event.head_commit.added, 'src/') || contains(github.event.head_commit.modified, 'src/')) }}
    run: clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp

So, above workflow  runs

a. if both c and cpp files exist
b. c files don't exist but cpp files exist

Note:
When c files exist but cpp files don't exist, it throws error at Run Static Code Analysis (C++) step.
If you don't want it to throw error (stop the workflow execution),

You can adjust your workflow based on your needs by using github-actions specific failure(), or !cancelled() conditionals on the next steps.

Another option is using bash expression on the Run Static Code Analysis (C++) step:


 - name: Run Static Code Analysis (C++)
    if: ${{ !cancelled() && (contains(github.event.head_commit.added, 'src/') || contains(github.event.head_commit.modified, 'src/')) }}
    run: clang++ --analyze src/*.cpp || true

reference

I came here looking how to disable the entire .yml file with a single condition.
Adding the conditions to each job individually is not feasible, because e.g. in a pull request, it spams a "job skipped" indicator for each skipped job, which is annoying (and duplicating the conditions is annoying).
The solution is to create a second .yml file, and conditionally run the primary file from it. Like this:
on:
  # Your triggers here, not in the main file.

jobs:
  test-pip-build:
    if: YOUR_CONDITION
    uses: ./.github/workflows/your_file.yml

